# backbone-forms plugin error with matching inputs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to validate a form. When I specify default data to populate the form that does not match, than validate via `commit`, I expectedly get an error logged (this is correct):

```
Errors: {"confirmedUsername":{"type":"match","message":"Usernames must match!"}}
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/franklovecchio/FkNwG/173/

When I specify default data that matches, then validate via `commit`, I get an actual console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'set' of undefined
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/franklovecchio/FkNwG/172/.

What gives?

Comment: I still don't get what you are trying to accomplish. But during the debugging i found out that the view does not contain the model. You should create view's like this `var form_view = new View({model:data});` replace the model with your instance

Comment: I updated the description - I'm not even using models, what do you mean?

Comment: what happened? Did the answer not work what else problems are you facing

Comment: I see the issue now. You CAN create a form without a model, but you must change it to getValue() instead of commit(). Thanks! Sometimes just need to read things a few times :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frank from the documentation it seemed you were doing it the wrong way.

#### JSFiddle (Working)

http://jsfiddle.net/FkNwG/176/

#### Reason

You can create a form without tying it to a model. For example, to create a form for a simple object of data:

```
var form = new Backbone.Form({
    data: { id: 123, name: 'Rod Kimble', password: 'cool beans' }, //Data to populate the form with
    schema: {
        id:         { type: 'Number' },
        name:       {},
        password:   { type: 'Password' }
    }
}).render();
```

Then instead of form.commit(), do:

```
var data = form.getValue(); //Returns object with new form values
```

i just changed `commit` to `getvalue()`